# Generating building footprints from street point

Tags: python, networkx, openstreetmap, arcgis, osmnx

I am using OSMNX to generate building footprints from a specific point. However, OSMNx doesn't display any footprints. I verified the same place from [GoogleMaps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/38%C2%B020'19.9%22S+143%C2%B035'56.5%22E/@-38.3389392,143.5984634,18z/data=!4m14!1m7!3m6!1s0x6ad30f18ffca8167:0x168fe9a9a538b363!2sWoods+St,+Colac+VIC+3250!3b1!8m2!3d-38.3389341!4d143.5990092!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d-38.3388498!4d143.5990131) where it shows there are many buildings around set point as shown in the below figure:

OSMNx Script

```
import osmnx
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
from IPython.display import Image
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import pprint
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

# get a graph for some city
G = ox.graph_from_place('Colac, Victoria, Australia', network_type='drive')

img_folder = 'images'
extension = 'png'
size = 640
dpi = 20

# #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def make_plot(place, point, network_type='drive', bldg_color='orange', dpi=400,
              dist=500, default_width=4, street_widths=None):
    gdf = ox.footprints.footprints_from_point(point=point, distance=dist)
    fig, ax = ox.plot_figure_ground(point=point, dist=dist, network_type=network_type, default_width=default_width,
                                    street_widths=street_widths, save=False, show=False, close=True)
    fig, ax = ox.footprints.plot_footprints(gdf, fig=fig, ax=ax, color=bldg_color, set_bounds=False,
                                            save=True, show=False, close=True, filename=place, dpi=dpi)
 # #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
place = 'Colac_buildings'
#Colac Lat,Lon
point = (-38.338850, 143.599013)
make_plot(place, point)
Image('{}/{}.{}'.format(img_folder, place, extension), height=size, width=size)
```

[image]

1. Does it mean the information is missing in OSMNx? What is the best way to get the building information or footprints?
2. Actually I am trying to extract addresses of all buildings in a specific area. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

OSMNx uses data from OpenStreetMap, not from Google Maps. For your location [-38.338850, 143.599013](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/-38.33885/143.59713&layers=N) there are no buildings in OSM yet (but there are several nearby, e.g. to the west).

To improve this you can create an OSM account and [start to improve the map](https://learnosm.org/en/beginner/). Besides building footprints you can also add missing addresses to OSM (if you have access to a compatible license). Afterwards you can retrieve them with a geocoder, for example [Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can understand that OSMNx uses OpenStreetMap and there is problem of missing information. Is there any other way to get the addresses of the buildings from a specific area?

Comment: I can only answer for OpenStreetMap. You can use a [geocoder](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) such as Nominatim to retrieve addresses. However this assumes that these addresses exist in OSM (except for cases where Nominatim uses a third-party address source additionally to OSM).